# Moving Collada file Lat Long

Tags: latitude-longitude, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, collada

I append a collada file into the plug-in, and then move it (append.Child, then remove.Child, then append.Child, etc) based on very small Latitude and Longitude increments.  When the Latitude increment = Longitude increment, however, the file moves in a rectangular fashion and NOT a square fashion.  What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't the "path" which the collada file travels be "square"?

The increment in both directions (lat or long) is the same increment (0.00001499817).  In trying to figure this out, I also noticed that the "circle" polygon code also shows up as an oval unless you place it along the equator.

Should I be assuming that a latitude increment EQUALS a longitude increment in Earth???

Anybody know what might be going on?  Thanks.  Paul

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be assuming that a latitude increment EQUALS a longitude
>   increment in Earth???

Do you assume the Earth is a perfect sphere?

Do you assume that latitude and longitude lines are evenly spaced out?

To quote someone else from a quick google search

> Longitude is the east-west (right/left) measurement on a map. It goes
>   from 180  degrees west to 0 (through Greenwich, London, UK) then to
>   180 degrees East.  180 degrees West or East is actually the same line
>   - its in the middle of the Pacific ocean.
>
> There are thus 360 lines of integer Longitude.
>
> Latitude goes from the Equator - 0 degrees, North to the North Pole at
>   90 degrees north.  Or south to the South Pole at 90 degrees south.
>
> There are thus 180 lines of integer latitude.
>
> Technically, you'd have to say that the number of possible lines is
>   actually infinite.  Since between any two lines you choose, no matter
>   how close together they are,  you can always fit a bunch more in
>   between them.